# Make Online Radio app faster in streaming

Tags: java, android

Hello i have make one radio app in that streaming is done from web

my source code is

when user click on button following code will be executed

```
      if (!NotifyService.iSserviceRunning) {
            new PlayRadio().execute("");
        }
```

// AYSNC class for start Service and create progressbar

```
  class PlayRadio extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            startService(new Intent(RadioActivity.this, NotifyService.class));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        try {
            PD = ProgressDialog.show(RadioActivity.this, "Tuning...", "Please Wait...");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

//Now service class will be

```
   public class NotifyService extends Service {

private static String RADIO_STATION_URL;
public static  MediaPlayer player;
public static boolean iSserviceRunning = false;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    RADIO_STATION_URL = getResources().getString(R.string.streamurl);
    nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    initializeMediaPlayer();
    startPlaying();
    iSserviceRunning = true;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    nm.cancel(R.string.service_started);
    stopPlaying();
    initializeMediaPlayer();
    iSserviceRunning = false;
}


private void startPlaying() {
    player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            player.start();

        }
    });
    new PrepareTask().execute();
}

private void stopPlaying() {
    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        player.pause();
        player.release();
    }
}

private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
    player = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        player.setDataSource(RADIO_STATION_URL);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private class PrepareTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        if(RadioActivity.PD!=null){
            if(RadioActivity.PD.isShowing()){
                RadioActivity.PD.dismiss();             
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... arg0) {
        try {
            player.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

is there any wrong i am doing becuase my client said that application is taking tooo much time for loading.. he told me that he has many such application which is loading fastly then my app

can any body suggest me is any wrong i have done in my code so it's taking much time?

Comment: Nothing stands out in terms of cyclomatic complexity.  Could it be that you have a slow connection and you're streaming a file that's too large for it?

Comment: Thanks Makoto so my code is perfect.. am i right?

Comment: Don't go assuming your code is perfect, though.  There's always one or two bugs just hiding, lurking, lying in wait.  Again, I don't see an issue that would cause the streaming to be too slow *in code*, so I'd check what you're streaming your music file at.